# Is there any issue with me splicing a continuous neutral wire and connecting a Wemo switch to it?

Tags: wiring

I have installed 3 wemo switches no issues at all. The neutral wire has been capped of with a wire nut in all the installs. I am trying to install another wemo switch in another location and it appears that the neutral wire is one continuous wire. Is there any issue with me splicing this wire and connecting the switch to this wire?

Answer (score 1):

No. If you're sure it's the grounded (neutral), and there's enough slack, go ahead and use it. Just make sure you turn off the power, before cutting the wire.